# Where are linker settings in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to add a lib to my VS 2017 project. However, there are no linker settings at all in the property pages.

Comment: You have to have a code file in your project before you will see the linker settings. C or C++ will do.

Comment: Hi Cody, If by code files you mean source code files, I have quite a few in my project.  I am trying to add a lib to the project as linker input, but cannot find the VS2017 Linker Settings.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The linker settings won't show up in an empty project. If that isn't the case for you, then consider showing us a screenshot of what you *do* see on your screen when you go to look for them. Nothing has changed about this in VS 2017 as far as I know.

Comment: Same here, can't find the linker.

Answer (score 0):

The original question didn't specify what they were clicking on, so here's what I was doing wrong: I was stupidly clicking on `OpenGLCourseApp.cpp` below, instead of `OpenGLCourseApp` indicated by the green arrow.

[image: Screenshot of Solution Explorer]

I know nothing about c++ nor Visual Studio, so this wasn't obvious to me.